# Install .IPA built for iPad on iPhone

Tags: ios

Is it possible to install .IPA file in iPhone which is built for iPad ?
If yes please tell me how to do

Comment: No you can not do it. You can run iPhone design in iPad but not iPad to iPhone.

Comment: If you have universal app then you can run on any device

Comment: so can we convert that IPA file to install on iPhone which is presently for iPad

Comment: If you are developer then convert you app to Universal (compatible to all iOS devices) then create .ipa file from it.

Comment: is it possible that we can convert it online

Comment: No, It's not possible to convert it online

Answer (score 0):

Depends how the app is built, you can set it for individual iphone models or ipad models.

Setting the Target Devices (iOS Only)
The Devices setting identifies the type of devices you want an iOS app to run on. There are two device types: iPhone and iPad. The iPhone type includes iPhone and iPod touch devices. The iPad type includes all iPad and iPad mini devices.

To set the target devices

In the project navigator, select the project and your target to display the project editor.
Click General and, if necessary, click the disclosure triangle next to Deployment Info to reveal the settings.
From the Devices pop-up menu, choose iPhone, iPad, or Universal (to target both families).
../Art/3_target_devices_setting_2x.png
For more information on configuring your app for iPhone, iPad, or both device families, see Advanced App Tricks in App Programming Guide for iOS.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends wether your application is `Universal` app or not.

If its `Universal` app & UDID of your iPhone included to the .ipa then it will work else not.